Reformulation of SOCP constraints for convex optimization problem
I am doing a convex optimization problem related to reactive power management
on a network. When trying to compile my problem on CVXPY, I have a problem with two constraints
which do not comply with DCP rules. By doing some research, I saw that there is
a possibility of reformulating them in order to respect the DCP rules in particular by using
the cp.SOC function of CVXPY. The problem is that I don't see how to do it.
The two constraints are as follows:

V_n[idx_from_combined[l]] * V_n[idx_to_combined[l]] * (np.sin(theta_max))^2 >= theta_l^2: where V_n and theta_l are variables of the optimization problem. NB: This constraint is conic, therefore convex.
Q_ol[l] * V_n[idx_from_combined[l]] >= (cp.sum(cp.square(P_sl[l]) + cp.square(Q_sl[l])))*X_l[l]:
which is a rotated SOCP constraint with Q_ol, V_n, P_sl and Q_sl which are optimization variables of my problem

Can you please help me reformulate these constraints?
When I compile my problem, with those constraints written in their actual form, the problem
doesn't follow the DCP rules.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

if you don't want to use rotated cones directly then quad_over_lin should be the way to model both case

@MichalAdamaszek Thank you for your answer ! Indeed I succeeded to make this constraint following the DCP rules by using the quad_over_lin function of CVXPY. That is an Overview of the modified constraints with quad_over_lin :   *Q_ol[l]b >= cp.quad_over_lin(P_sl[l], V_n[idx_from_combined[l]]) + cp.quad_over_lin(Q_sl[l], V_n[idx_from_combined[l]]) , *V_n[idx_from_combined[l]]a >= cp.quad_over_lin(theta_l[l],V_n[idx_to_combined[l]]) where a = (np.sin(theta_max))**2 and b = 1/(X_l[l])
